# Show that $m(\{x\in[0,1]:\text{$x$ lies in infinitely many $E_j$}\})\geq\frac{1}{2}$ when $m(E_j)\geq\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> **Question:** Suppose $E_1, E_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ with $m(E_j)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$.  Show that $m(\{x\in[0,1]:\text{$x$ lies in infinitely many $E_j$}\})\geq\dfrac{1}{2}$, where $m$ is the one dimensional Lebesgue measure.

My thoughts: I would imagine that one could use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma here.  The issue is that for the Borel Cantelli Lemma I need $\sum_{j=1}^\infty m(E_j)<\infty$, but since $m(E_j)\geq\frac{1}{2}$, then I can't use it.  Now, if the hypotheses of the Borel Cantelli Lemma were satisfied, then $m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{n=k}^\infty E_j)=0$.  Which, to my understanding, is the same things as saying that if $E=\{x\in[0,1]:\text{$x$ lies in infinitely many $E_j$}\}\implies m(E)=0$, where $E$ is the set we are dealing with in the question.  So, I am wondering if there is a general way to sort of "shift" the Borel Cantelli Lemma.  Or, is there another way to go about this problem?  Any thoughts, ideas, answers, etc. are always greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_j=[0,1]\setminus E_j$. Then  $m (F_j ) \leq \frac 1  2$ and , by Fatou's Lemma, $\int \lim \inf I_{F_j} dm \leq \lim \inf m(F_j) \leq \frac 1 2$  Can you finish ?

[ Note that $\lim \inf I_{F_j}$ is  the indicator function of $\lim \inf F_j$].

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm sort of stuck on the "$x$ must lie in infinitely many of the $E_j$" part.  For instance, can we say that since $\lim \inf m(F_j)\leq\frac{1}{2}$, then since we are working with subsets of $[0,1]$, WLOG, we can choose $F_j$ to be, at most, $[0,\frac{1}{2})$.  So, since $m(E_j)\geq\frac{1}{2}$, then we can choose $E_j$ to be, at least, $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.... then since there are an infinite number of $x$'s that lie in that range, we'd get the result....?  Something sort of like this?

Comment: @User7238 I have proved that $\lim \inf F_j$ has measure at most $\frac1  2$. The set of points that belong to infinitely many $E_j$'s is exactly the complement of $\lim \inf F_j$ so  its measure is $\geq 1-\frac  1 2 =\frac 1  2$.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see... that's a nice and easy way of doing it!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Just real quick, why exactly is the complement of $\lim\inf F_j$ exactly the set we are looking for?  For example, how do we know that those $x$ values don't just lie in a finite number of the $E_j$'s?

Comment: $\lim \inf F_j$ is the set of points which belong to all but finite number of $F_j$'s. So if a point is not in this set then it cannot belong to $F_j$ for all $n >N$ whatever $N$ is. This implies that it is in $E_j=F_j^{c}$ for infinitely many values of $j$. @User7238

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.  So, could we consider, for example, that $\lim\sup F_j$ is the set of points which belong to infinitely many of the $F_j$'s?